# C# check null on an object and its property

Tags: c#, null

I'd like to tidy up this piece of code, any idea?

- 1 object is not null
- 1 of its property is not null either

  ```
  var v = Values.Find(x => x.id.Equals(Properties.Resources.myString));
  if (v != null && v.Property != null)
  {
  // do something with 'v.Property'
  }
  ```

Comment: Do you want to do something if `v.Property` is null or isn't null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) will probably best serve you here with the null conditional operator:

```
var v = Values.Find(x => x.id.Equals(Properties.Resources.myString));
var result = v?.Property?.DoSomething();
```

Comment: @user2864740 Where does he have `== null`?

Comment: In `v.Property == null`

Comment: @user2864740 You're right. OP should clarify though, as his title says "double null check"

Comment: thanks for your inputs guys, I've updated it, hopefully this now makes more sense